# Create a contact list with the user information list

Tags: sharepoint

I want to populate a list in sharepoint 2013 foundation with the information found in the user information list. The user information list is found at /_catalogs/users/simple.aspx and contains all the entries of the users.

Is it possible to do this with powershell or any other method, NOT using c#, vb etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to populate Contacts list with the information found in the user information list using JSOM

```
(function(){
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var userInfoList = context.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_siteUserInfoList();   //source list
   var userItems = userInfoList.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
   var contactsList = context.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('Contacts');  //target list

   context.load(contactsList);
   context.load(userItems);
   context.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){


       for(var i = 0; i < userItems.get_count();i++){
           var item = userItems.getItemAtIndex(i);

           //mapping properties from user item to contact item  
           var contactEntry = {
             'Title': item.get_item('Title'), 
             'FullName': item.get_item('Name'),
             'Email': item.get_item('EMail'),
             'WorkPhone': item.get_item('MobilePhone'),
             'WebPage': item.get_item('WebSite')
           };
           //prepare contact item
           createContact(contactsList,contactEntry);

       }


       context.executeQueryAsync(
       function(){
          console.log('Completed');      
       }, 
       function(sender,args){
          console.log(args.get_message());    
       });

   }, 
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());    
   });

   function createContact(list, itemProps)
   {
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        for(var propName in itemProps) {
           listItem.set_item(propName, itemProps[propName]) 
        }
        listItem.update();    
   }


})();
```

> The script could be converted into PowerShell script if needed.

Comment: Thanks, how is the easiest way to apply this? Add it as a script in a web part?

Comment: I believe the easiest way would be to copy this script into the Browser console and just run it. More details about running the script in IE could be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I get this error: List 'Contacts' does not exist at site with URL, The name of the list is Contacts, located at: ~/product/Lists/Contacts/AllItems.aspx....

Comment: My list was on a subsite and some of the contact entrys wasn't correct. So a little tweak of your code did the job. Thank you so much! :D

Comment: Hello again. The userproperties you are demonstrating, like Title and EMail. Where can i find a list of available properties. Don't really know how to get that photo from the user information list etc.